# Python ipywidgets interact calls method twice

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I wrote some code and noticed that the `interact` method from ipywidgets calls the method of which the arguments are to be manipulated twice. I was wondering why that is and if it is possible to make it only call once. From the documentation it seems that is not a bug of my code but that this is wanted.

Here is a small example:

```
def func(x=0):
  print(x)

interact(func, x = widgets.IntSlider(min = -1, max=1, step=1),)
```

As you will see it prints twice the argument of `x`.

Comment: The code only displays `x` once for me. Is this the full code? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Hey, yeah after restarting VSC it displays it only once for me too. Am wondering what might have caused it. But thanks for checking!